# Passing data correctly with angularfire2 / ionic2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, ionic3, angularfire2

I have a simple structure in my Database:

[image: Firebase structure]

The app logic here: I create a list with some data with the function to delete each list item separately.

I´m using the angularefire2 plugin for database communication. The code to get data looks like this in **component**:

```
// Set variables
currentUserID: any;
visits: any[] = [];
selectedVisit: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private dbAction: DbActionsProvider, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
    // Build Current User ID
    this.currentUserID = this.dbAction.currentUserID().subscribe(data => {
      this.currentUserID = data.uid;
    });
  }

ngOnInit() {
    // Get data
    this.afDatabase.object('data/users/' + this.currentUserID + '/visits')
      .snapshotChanges().map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.toJSON();
        return data;
      })
      .subscribe(result => {
        Object.keys(result).map(key => {
          this.visits.push({ 'key': key, 'data':result[key]
          });
      }); console.log(this.visits)
    })
  }
```

The code in my **view**:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let visit of visits | orderBy:'date' : false" (ionDrag)="onSelectedVisit(visit)">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-man" md="md-man" item-start></ion-icon>
    <strong>{{ !visit.data.name == '' ? visit.data.name : 'Unbekannt' }}</strong>
    <p>Musterstraße 8, 66130 Saarbrücken</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button>Bearbeiten</button>
    <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteVisit()">Löschen</button>
  </ion-item-options>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="visit.id"></ion-input>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Ok..now I want that the user can delete items. For this I need access to the key reference ($key in firebase, but not works.....)...so I had to build my own object with this key field in the top. Not a pretty solution...do you have another idea?

**The problem:**

If the user swipe an item to see the Delete-Option, I pass data with (ionDrag)="onSelectedVisit(visit). My code in component for this function:

```
onSelectedVisit(visit) {
  this.selectedVisit = visit.key;
  console.log(this.selectedVisit);
}

deleteVisit() {
  this.afDatabase.list('data/users/' + this.currentUserID + '/visits').remove(this.selectedVisit);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(VisitsPage);
}
```

If I not navigate back to VisitsPage (same page) I´ll see duplicates in my list because of the own builded object before.....so I need a more elegant solution..

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! Answering your own question is not forbidden (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the "ask a question" page)

Comment: Oh, okay! :) I did, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a pretty solution:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.itemsRef = db.list('messages');
    // Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
    this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }
  addItem(newName: string) {
    this.itemsRef.push({ text: newName });
  }
  updateItem(key: string, newText: string) {
    this.itemsRef.update(key, { text: newText });
  }
  deleteItem(key: string) {    
    this.itemsRef.remove(key); 
  }
  deleteEverything() {
    this.itemsRef.remove();
  }
}
```

Reference: [Github - Angularfire2 Docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list)